# Python dictionary to dataframe issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to take api requests and put them in a format accessible for SQL - at the moment I have nested dictionaries which i am unsure of how to fix quickly.

This is the code currently,

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
Name= "swing_data_"+timestr+".json"

api_results = {}
for items in States:
        url = url_swing + items
        request = requests.get(url)
        api_results[items]=(request.json())



with open(Name, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(api_results, f)
```

And the dataframe output like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([api_results])
df.head()
```

### Just edited question,

Want to format the data with the columns being the type, suburb etc, and having the state as another column

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: ^^ Just edited question, Want to format the data with the columns being the type, suburb etc, and having the state as another column

Comment: Can you please share a sample input of dataframe and the expected output, not in the form of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dictionary of `DataFrame`s and then join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last remove second level of `MultiIndex`, `rename` it and convert index to column `key`:

```
d = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in api_results.items()}

df = pd.concat(d).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('key').reset_index()
print (df)
   key   type           suburb              street                 oldRange  \
0  VIC  House    Carlton North   114 Garton Street  $4,400,000 - $4,800,000   
1  VIC  House    Fitzroy North  24 Egremont Street  $1,600,000 - $1,750,000   
2  VIC  House   Hamlyn Heights    6 Heritage Drive  $1,180,000 - $1,280,000   
3  VIC  House  Caulfield South      24 Emma Street  $1,900,000 - $2,089,999   

                  newRange dollarDelta percentDelta  daysDelta  
0               $4,100,000   -$700,000         -14%         42  
1  $1,950,000 - $2,100,000    $350,000          20%         62  
2    $990,000 - $1,050,000   -$230,000         -17%         82  
3  $1,800,000 - $1,980,000   -$109,999          -5%         33
```

If possible, create `DataFrame`s in first loop:

```
api_results = {}
for items in States:
        url = url_swing + items
        request = requests.get(url)
        api_results[items]= pd.DataFrame(request.json())


df = pd.concat(api_results).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('key').reset_index()
```